# Drupal Chaos Tool Suit Custom Ruleset error

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-ctools

I am using `Drupal core 6.14` and `Chaos Tool Suit 6.x-1.12` and in the ctool custom access rulesets page I am getting error when loading the ctools modal dialog.

The POST request url in my local machine is `http://localhost/drupal/?q=ctools/context/ajax/add/ctools_export_ui-ctools_access_ruleset/requiredcontext/%3A%3Aadd/node`.

Response status is 200 and the statusText is "parsererror". It's giving the error alert,

```
An error occurred at http://localhost/drupal/?q=ctools/context/ajax/add/ctools_export_ui-ctools_access_ruleset/requiredcontext/%3A%3Aadd/node.

Error Description: "[ { "command": "settings", "argument": { "basePath": "/drupal/", "cron": { "basePath": "/drupal/?q=poormanscron", "runNext": 1362598387 } } }, { "command": "css_files", "argument": [ { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/activities/activities.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/alert/alert.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/complaint/complaint.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/employeeform/employeeform.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/evvodashboard/evvodashboard.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/evvodashboard/js/jquery.ui.core.js?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/evvodashboard/js/jquery.ui.widget.js?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/evvodashboard/js/jquery.ui.mouse.js?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/evvodashboard/js/jquery.ui.sortable.js?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/hblogin/hblogin.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/management/css/management.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/ownerregisterform/ownerregisterform.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/phonebook/phonebook.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/propertyform/propertyform.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/propertymanagement/propertymanagement.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/tenentregisterform/tenentregisterform.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/cck/theme/content-module.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/filefield/filefield.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/panels/css/panels.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/cck/modules/fieldgroup/fieldgroup.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/files/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css?0", "media": "all" }, { "file": "/drupal/sites/all/themes/rubik/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css?0", "media": "all" } ] }, { "command": "scripts", "argument": [ "/drupal/misc/jquery.js", "/drupal/misc/drupal.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/activities/activities.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/alert/alert.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/alert/alert_1.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/complaint/complaint.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/emergency/emergency.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/employeeform/employeeform.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/evvodashboard/evvodashboard.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/facilityform/facilityform.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/gtrans/gtranslate.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/insurance/insurance.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/maintenance/maintenance.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/mycalendar/calendar.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/ownerregisterform/ownerregisterform.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/phonebook/phonebook.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/privatemsg/privatemsg.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/profile_edit/profile_edit.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/propertyform/propertyform.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/propertymanagement/propertymanagement.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/tenentregisterform/tenentregisterform.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/vendors/vendors.js", "/drupal/sites/default/files/jstimer/timer.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/panels/js/panels.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/poormanscron/poormanscron.js", "/drupal/sites/all/modules/webfm/modules/webfm_mp3/mp3player/audio-player.js", "/drupal/sites/all/files/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js", "/drupal/sites/all/files/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js", "/drupal/sites/all/files/js/jquery_alphanumeric.js", "/drupal/sites/all/files/js/accode.js", "/drupal/sites/all/files/development-bundle/ui/ui.progressbar.js", "/drupal/sites/all/themes/rubik/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" ] }, { "command": "modal_display", "title": "Add required context \"Node\"", "output": "\x3cform action=\"/drupal/?q=ctools/context/ajax/add/ctools_export_ui-ctools_access_ruleset/requiredcontext/%3A%3Aadd/node\"  accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" method=\"post\" id=\"ctools-edit-requiredcontext-form\"\x3e\n\x3cdiv\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"modal-form clear-block\"\x3e\x3cdiv class=\"description\"\x3eA node object.\x3c/div\x3e\x3cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"requiredcontext[name]\" id=\"edit-requiredcontext-name\" value=\"node\"  /\x3e\n\x3cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"requiredcontext[id]\" id=\"edit-requiredcontext-id\" value=\"1\"  /\x3e\n\x3cdiv  class=\"form-item form-item-labeled\" id=\"edit-requiredcontext-identifier-wrapper\"\x3e\r\n      \x3clabel  for=\"edit-requiredcontext-identifier\"\x3eIdentifier: \x3c/label\x3e\r\n    \x3cinput type=\"text\" maxlength=\"128\" name=\"requiredcontext[identifier]\" id=\"edit-requiredcontext-identifier\" value=\"Node\" class=\"form-text fluid\" /\x3e      \x3cdiv class=\'description\'\x3eEnter a name to identify this required context on administrative screens.\x3c/div\x3e\r\n  \x3c/div\x3e\r\n\x3cdiv  class=\"form-item form-item-labeled\" id=\"edit-requiredcontext-keyword-wrapper\"\x3e\r\n      \x3clabel  for=\"edit-requiredcontext-keyword\"\x3eKeyword: \x3c/label\x3e\r\n    \x3cinput type=\"text\" maxlength=\"128\" name=\"requiredcontext[keyword]\" id=\"edit-requiredcontext-keyword\" value=\"node\" class=\"form-text fluid\" /\x3e      \x3cdiv class=\'description\'\x3eEnter a keyword to use for substitution in titles.\x3c/div\x3e\r\n  \x3c/div\x3e\r\n\x3c/div\x3e\x3cinput type=\"submit\" name=\"op\" id=\"edit-next\" value=\"Save\"  class=\"form-submit\" /\x3e\n\x3cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_build_id\" id=\"form-fec71d3cab0e5c35520c4ffc4dd5632f\" value=\"form-fec71d3cab0e5c35520c4ffc4dd5632f\"  /\x3e\n\x3cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_token\" id=\"edit-ctools-edit-requiredcontext-form-form-token\" value=\"cf83cbf84d13b7631f47c02ddec33b01\"  /\x3e\n\x3cinput type=\"hidden\" name=\"form_id\" id=\"edit-ctools-edit-requiredcontext-form\" value=\"ctools_edit_requiredcontext_form\"  /\x3e\n\n\x3c/div\x3e\x3c/form\x3e\n" } ]"
```

I don't have any JavaScript errors in firebug console and php error in php error log.

Comment: It's fixed with this patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/479368_drupal_to_js_all_escaped_13.patch